# How not to send the command line argument to the imported file

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 python scripts (aa.py and bb.py) which accepts command line argument.

I'm importing aa.py in bb.py. The argument which I give to bb.py during execution it is getting passed to aa.py too.

I do not want aa.py to get the command line input which was sent to bb.py, as it has to get a different set of inputs.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: If `aa` is being imported by `bb`, how do you expect to give it its own set of command line inputs?

Comment: glibdub, exactly that the problem is. I wanted to know is there any way we can achieve this. At the moment I'm importing aa just to access the final value which it returns. I will be deriving some more value from aa's output in bb.